# Need to add layout dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my Layout , I have nested Linear layout inside another linear layout which is nested inside an Scroll view. Now i want to add an Linear layout dynamically (I may even add upto 10) inside `android:id="@+id/formLayout"` i.e beneth `android:id="@+id/secondLayout"`

Original Layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="420dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
        <!-- LinearLayout Inside ScrollView -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/formLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <!-- Serial Layout -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/secondLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">
                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/serialno_label"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp">
                    <AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/fieldSerial"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:hint="@string/txt_sno_text"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textIsSelectable="false"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Dynamic Layout needs to be added :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/sixthLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="2">

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/attr2_label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingStart="10dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/fieldAttr2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:hint="Attribute 2"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Can some one help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `LayoutInflater` to create a view based on your layout template, and then inject it into the view where you need it.

```
 public static NavigableMap<Integer, String> navigableMap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();

    public static int count = 0; // to count no of views added
     public static void add_new(final Activity activity)
        {
            final LinearLayout linearLayoutForm = (LinearLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.formLayout);
            final LinearLayout newView = (LinearLayout) activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view_to_add, null);
            newView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            final EditText edit_new = (EditText) newView.findViewById(R.id.fieldAttr2);

            edit_new.setId(id++); // It will assign a different id to edittext each time while adding new view.
            Log.i("actv id",edit_new.getId()+""); // You can check the id assigned to it here.

            // use a Hashmap or navigable map (helpful if want to navigate through map)
            // to store the values inserted in edittext along with its ids.

            edit_new.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                navigableMap.put(edit_new.getId(), edit_new.getText().toString());
                Log.i("navigablemap", navigableMap.toString());
                }
            });

            // you can get values directly through map by referencing its ids.

            // OR

            EditText actv_uc = (EditText) linearLayoutForm.findViewById(navigableMap.lastKey()); 
            // Provide the id of edittext you want to access
            actv_uc.getText(); // to get value of EditText
            actv_uc.setText("");
            linearLayoutForm.addView(newView);
            count++;
        }
```

Call this function whenever you want to add new view. If you are calling this in Activity, then there is no need to pass Activity object as parameter. but if you are using this in fragment, then need to pass a Parent Activity object to function.

Very easy and helpful tutorial for adding views dynamically :-
http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/05/add-and-remove-view-dynamically.html

Hope this will help you. Thank you

Comment: Thank you ! I have an doubt . Lets consider i create 5 fields. How do i change its placeholder while creating and also how do i get its value ?

Comment: See my updated answer, I will like to help you in any doubt. Thanks @user3383301

Comment: Thanks a lot. Made my day :)

Comment: Very happy to help you. @user3383301

Comment: Thanks @PriyaJagtap

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
LinearLayout myRoot = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.formLayout);
LayoutInflater inf = LayoutInflater.from(yourContext);
View child;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    child = inf.inflate(R.layout.your_added_layout, null);
    child.setId("textView"+i);
    // can set layoutparam if needed.
    myRoot.addView(child);
}
```